# Ubuntu server 11 showing weird characters on console

Tags: ubuntu

I've installed Ubuntu server 11 after my last hard drive failed to perform. The install process and GRUB screen are OK but I have a problem with the console. I attached two photos because it's difficult for me to describe this issue. I have little knowledge about Linux. My server is used for git, file server, print server. I played with this command `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` but no effect.

[image]

It's nothing physicality wrong with my display or my memory(it's on board). I have run a memtest, and besides that withe the previous version of Ubuntu I've had no problems.

The problem.
[image]

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: Is a dell optiplex gx50. Video is onboard. The chipset is intel 810.

Comment: I can confirm this problem on an old Dell Machine that I just installed 11.04 Server on. This could be a bug. I'm hoping you find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try temporary disabling [KMS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/KernelModeSetting) pressing `e` in the GRUB menu and navigate using your arrow keys to the `linux` line. Before `--`, add `nomodeset`. Be sure to have a space before and after it, it should look like:

```
quiet nomodeset --
```

You should install `openssh-server` so you can remotely manage your server even if the displays fails to show text. See also the [Ubuntu wiki on SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH)

Comment: Is this what i should try to do? I get the same screen. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-fkFhD9WY2bg/ThGkE_XCjjI/AAAAAAAAHH0/Dwg6S1fgqsE/s912/IMG_1956.JPG btw, i have ssh and is running ok.

Comment: That's indeed the command. I can't find the graphics card on http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/opgx50/en/ug/specs.htm , can you boot in Recovery mode? (Hold Shift to get to the GRUB2 menu). If not, can you post the output of `lspci | grep VGA` (using SSH ;) )? Can you also upload the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/kern.log` to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and post the links?

Comment: Thank you for your time. The kern.log and the lspci | grep VGA output is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/638291/ I have ubuntu server, so i think that Xorg.0.log is not in my system for that reason. I will also try the first method. Now I'm not at the office.